# How do I revoke an access token in IdentityServer via code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I've created a new .NET Core 3 web application via the official React SPA template (`dotnet new react`). This combines the API server and [Identity](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) server in the same backend application.

Now I need to revoke an access token **not** via the react client, but via the API server. Normally I would do this by calling the `/revoke` endpoint (if I use a reference token instead of a JWT). But it seems strange to me to make an API call from the same application to itself just to revoke the token.

So how do I revoke an access token via code in IdentityServer? Bonus points if this also works for a JWT based token (since that is the default in the React SPA template).

Additional information: I've configured IdentityServer to work with ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: You can't revoke JWT access tokens. That's the nature of a JWT token, it remains valid untill it expires. What you can do as alternative is to maintain a RevokeJwtList in the client, so it knows when a token is revoked.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Noted. Thanks! I thought I might be able to expire it since the API server lives in the same app as IdentityServer. So technically it can take the ID of the JWT and check it against a list of revoked IDs. I'll leave the revocation part in the question for a bit, but I might remove it soon since it might subtract from the main question.